How to search for single quote in Kibana
I have some logs in Elasticsearch 8.12.2 that I want to filter in Kibana. I want to seach for logs with a message field containing the exact string
Externalkey'' (That's "Externalkey" followed by two single quotes.)
When I write
message: "Externalkey''"
in the search field in Kibana 8.12.2 I get matches for Externalkey no matter if it is followed by quotes or not.
Based on Googling the question, I have tried
message: "Externalkey\'\'"
and
message: "Externalkey\\'\\'"
and
message: "Externalkey\\\\'\\\\'"
as well as
message: Externalkey''
with the same result.
How do I search for single quotes in Kibana?

no need for the quotes '' as long as you are using (match), because the analyzer is going to delete them already, just search for "Externalkey keyValue", and make sure that the fuzziness is zero and the operator is AND,
here you can read more about it:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html
if you need an exact phrase with quotations, and even if there is a gap between the Externalkey and the keyValue, you can use match_phrase, read about the match_phrase here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html
you can use slop to specify the gap value.
also you can use terms for exact match, write it like this:
"terms" : ["Externalkey", "keyValue"]

and make sure that the operator is AND also
terms:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html
for quotation part:
single quotation doesn't need the slash /, in other words search will be like this:
"Externalkey'keyValue'"

but if you are searching for a double quotation, the search will be like this:
"Externalkey\"keyValue\""

but when you search like this, if your logs are text type then the text analyzer is going to delete the quotations. so you should use match_phrase to keep the phrase as it.

read about query_string as you can also perform exact match using it, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78279349/elasticsearch-query-function-score-ignores-quotes-in-query-string

Thank you for the answer. However, it seems to answer anything but what I am asking. I just want to use Kibana to search for the exact string "Externalkey''" (that's Externalkey and two single quotes) in the field "message". None of your comments, examples or links bring me closer to that. The point is that I want to find logs where Externalkey is empty, not where it has a value.

use (match_phrase), I tried it and it worked I searched for exactly "Externalkey''", and I got only the fields that have exactly (Externalkey'').

there is a link explaining the match_phrase in the answer above

But how does that apply to Kibana? I am not trying to build my own program for searching Elasticsearch.

it is kibana already, GET /_search
{
"query": {
"match_phrase": {
"message": "your text here"
}
}
}
